# OpenGL Texture Coordinates Have No Effect

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I cannot get texture coordinates to have any effect on what is rendered on screen. My texture constantly seemed to rendering from 0,0 to 1,1.

The method I am using is to send the following buffer layout: x,y,u,v (xy: vertex position and u,v texture coordinates).

However, changing the values u & v have no effect on the rendered texture.

I've removed a lot of surrounding code to try and make it easier to read, but I can post it in full if the problem isn't immediately obvious to someone.



**Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 mytextpos;

out vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform mat4 u_Model;

void main()
{
gl_Position = u_Model * vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
v_TexCoord = mytextpos;
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

in vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_Texture;

void main()
{
color = texture(u_Texture, v_TexCoord);
}
```

**My Rectangle Class Constructor:**

```
// GENERATE BUFFERS
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayObject);
glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBufferId);
glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBufferObjectId);


Indices = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

unsigned int numberOfVertices = Vertices.size();
unsigned int numberOfIndices = Indices.size();

glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBufferObjectId);

Vertices = {
    0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f, 0.5f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};


// ADD BUFFER DATA
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Vertices.size() * sizeof(float), Vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );


// ARRANGE ATTRIBUTES
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), nullptr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), nullptr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, numberOfIndices * sizeof(unsigned int), Indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );`
```

**Render Function:**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

GLint u_Texture = glGetUniformLocation( shader.getId(), "u_Texture" );
glUniform1i( u_Texture, 0 );

GLint u_Model = glGetUniformLocation( shader.getId(), "u_Model" );
glUniformMatrix4fv( u_Model, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( rect.TransformMatrix() ) );

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, rect.Indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

// SWAP BUFFERS
glfwSwapBuffers( _window->WindowInstance );
glfwPollEvents();
```

My program runs, but my texture is mapped between 0,0 and 1,0 no matter what my vertex or u,v positions are. I would expect the texture to be interpolated between the u,v coordinates for each vertex?

Comment: You data doesn't fit your description. You have 4 floats per vertex, but claim that you have a `x,y,z,u,v` layout. But this requires 5 floats per vertex.

Comment: Oops... my mistake it should indeed be x,y,v,w. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attribute setup is wrong:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), nullptr);
```

This tells OpenGL that it should attach the first two floats of each vertex to the `mytextpos` attribute. But you actually want it to read the 3rd and 4th float. Thus you have to set the offset such that it skips the first two floats:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you greatly! I completely missed this parameters when reading the documentation, I assumed the offset was calculated using the location. Thanks again!

Comment: @James if this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.